# Model binder does not fill items in nested lists

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have the following model:

```cs
public class ConfigurationPolicyModel
{
    public ConfigurationPolicyModel()
    {
        Properties = new List<Property>();
    }

    public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }

    public class Property
    {
        public Property()
        {
            Value = new List<ValueItem>();
        }

        public List<ValueItem> Value { get; set; }

        public class ValueItem
        {
            public string Data { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

The simplified controller is as the following:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditPolicy(ConfigurationPolicyModel model)
{
    foreach (var prop in model.Properties)
    {
        var n = prop.Value.Count; // The problem is here: prop.Value is empty
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem context is the following:

- The EditPolicy view is complex enough, where Knockout.JS is used for dynamic adding/removing value items, an input element looks like the following:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" type="text" data-bind="value: Data" name="Properties[@i].ValueItem" />
```

But at form submitting, JavaScript code updates name attributes to have correct names like `Properties[0].Value[0].Data`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < viewModel.properties().length; ++i)
{
    var valueItems = $('input[name="Properties[' + i + '].ValueItem"]');

    for (var j = 0; j < valueItems.length; ++j)
    {
        $(valueItems[j]).attr("name", "Properties[" + i + "].Value[" + j + "].Data");
    }
}
```

The form data of HTTP request in Fiddler looks as the following (in WebForms mode):

[image: Property Value Items]

The raw payload of the HTTP request is the following:

```
Id=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&Level=Platform&Name=SmsPolicy&InheritanceLevels[0].Level=SafeCenter&InheritanceLevels[0].InheritanceType=Force&InheritanceLevels[1].Level=TeamSafe&InheritanceLevels[1].InheritanceType=Force&Properties[0].Name=Providers&Properties[0].ValueIsSequence=True&Properties[0].Value[0].Data=O2&Properties[0].Value[1].Data=Telecom&Properties[0].Value[2].Data=&Properties[0].Value[3].Data=&Properties[0].Minimum=&Properties[0].Maximum=&Targets[0].Level=Platform&Targets[0].Name=Platform&Targets[0].Selected=true&Targets[0].Selected=false&Targets[1].Level=SafeCenter&Targets[1].Name=SafeCenters&Targets[1].Selected=true&Targets[1].Selected=false&Targets[1].Items[0].Level=SafeCenter&Targets[1].Items[0].OwnerId=7292f9aa-b168-43ab-83a7-db193599d02f&Targets[1].Items[0].Name=Google+Inc.&Targets[1].Items[0].Selected=true&Targets[1].Items[0].Selected=false&Targets[1].Items[1].Level=SafeCenter&Targets[1].Items[1].OwnerId=6c481d66-0ece-4269-8256-c02d3b8c5109&Targets[1].Items[1].Name=SC11&Targets[1].Items[1].Selected=true&Targets[1].Items[1].Selected=false&Targets[1].Items[2].Level=SafeCenter&Targets[1].Items[2].OwnerId=9afd1968-6742-435d-919e-36068ff4b235&Targets[1].Items[2].Name=SC2&Targets[1].Items[2].Selected=true&Targets[1].Items[2].Selected=false&Targets[1].Items[3].Level=SafeCenter&Targets[1].Items[3].OwnerId=995813e1-91d4-4fad-bf10-fbafa0354cbb&Targets[1].Items[3].Name=SC4&Targets[1].Items[3].Selected=true&Targets[1].Items[3].Selected=false&Targets[1].Items[4].Level=SafeCenter&Targets[1].Items[4].OwnerId=acbd68a8-cb9b-4e50-8eeb-59b374fedae0&Targets[1].Items[4].Name=SC5&Targets[1].Items[4].Selected=true&Targets[1].Items[4].Selected=false&Targets[2].Level=TeamSafe&Targets[2].Name=TeamSafes&Targets[2].Selected=true&Targets[2].Selected=false
```

- When a form is posting to server, the form data actually contains such fields, the Fiddler confirms that. Moreover, I assigned (via `ModelBinderAttribute`) custom model binder to watch the fields actually do reach the model binder, - yes, they do.
- But when the default binder creates an instance of the model - a `Property` instance has no items in its `Value` list.
- And the most strange point: this problem occurs time by time, and it seems depending on number of value items. If a property has one value item, the `Value` list will be probably filled, but in case of six value items no items inserted to the `Value` list.

Could anybody please advise how to resolve the problem? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Apart from the problem, why you have nested the class ValueItem?

Comment: Can you show your EditPolicy view?

Comment: @testCoder     I've added description for EditPolicy view. If still not enough details, please notify.

Comment: @Asif          Nested types are encapsulated in the corresponding model class to keep namespaces clearer. The model binder supports type nesting.

Comment: Could you show your Fiddler dump of the POST request payload? Or if you are using FireBug or Chrome Developer Toolbar you could directly get it from the Net tab.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I added Fiddler screenshot - do you need exactly full dump of the POST request? Please notify if so.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the numbering is continuous. 
Every Id that is skipped causes all greater Ids to not be populated in the model.

Concretely, I made a similar test in an MVC website and noticed that:

- when I have on the client the Ids 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 all elements are correctly populated in the model
- for Ids 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 only elements 1, 2 and 3 are populated (5, 6, and 7 are lost because of the missing 4).

Comment: Yes, indices are continuous, no any gaps. I added the Fiddler screenshot to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="text" name="Properties[0].Value[0].Data" value="O2" />
    <input type="text" name="Properties[0].Value[1].Data" value="Telecom" />
    <input type="text" name="Properties[0].Value[2].Data" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="Properties[0].Value[3].Data" value="" />

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and binds correctly to the following action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditPolicy(ConfigurationPolicyModel model)
{
    return View();
}
```

The following payload is sent over the wire:

```
Properties[0].Value[0].Data = O2
Properties[0].Value[1].Data = Telecom
Properties[0].Value[2].Data =
Properties[0].Value[3].Data =
```

So if this doesn't work for you there might be some other reason such as a custom model binder which interferes with the default convention or your request payload doesn't look as shown here.

Comment: I added the payload of the HTTP request that leads to the binder failure. It has exactly the same name=value pairs for value items. We don't use any custom model binders, only default model binder.